# TensorFlow seems to modify both class and instance object

Tags: python, tensorflow, class, object

I have observed that the `TensorFlow` methods like `assign_add` and `assign_sub` modify the variables of both object and class (if exist). Here is a simple code to reproduce my observation. Can anyone please clarify about this behavior (`assign_sub` and `assign_add` modifying both class and instance attributes)?

```py
#a python class
class myc_base():
    a=1.
    def __init__(self, b=1.):
        self.b=b
    def add(self, to_add=1.):
        self.a+=to_add
        self.b+=to_add
    def sub(self, to_sub=1.):
        self.a-=to_sub
        self.b-=to_sub

obj_base=myc_base()

print(f'Init.     -- class.a: {myc_base.a} | obj.a: {obj_base.a}, obj.b: {obj_base.b}')
obj_base.add(5.)
print(f'after add -- class.a: {myc_base.a} | obj.a: {obj_base.a}, obj.b: {obj_base.b}')
obj_base.sub(2.)
print(f'after sub -- class.a: {myc_base.a} | obj.a: {obj_base.a}, obj.b: {obj_base.b}')
```

Output:

```
Init.     -- class.a: 1.0 | obj.a: 1.0, obj.b: 1.0
after add -- class.a: 1.0 | obj.a: 6.0, obj.b: 6.0
after sub -- class.a: 1.0 | obj.a: 4.0, obj.b: 4.0
```

With TensorFlow:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

#a class for tf operations
class myc_tf():
    a=tf.Variable(1.)
    def __init__(self, b=tf.Variable(1.)):
        self.b=b
    def add(self, to_add=1.):
        self.a.assign_add(to_add)
        self.b.assign_add(to_add)
    def sub(self, to_sub=1.):
        self.a.assign_sub(to_sub)
        self.b.assign_sub(to_sub)

obj_tf=myc_tf()

print(f'Init.     -- class.a: {myc_tf.a.numpy()} | obj.a: {obj_tf.a.numpy()}, obj.b: {obj_tf.b.numpy()}')
obj_tf.add(5.)
print(f'after add -- class.a: {myc_tf.a.numpy()} | obj.a: {obj_tf.a.numpy()}, obj.b: {obj_tf.b.numpy()}')
obj_tf.sub(2.)
print(f'after sub -- class.a: {myc_tf.a.numpy()} | obj.a: {obj_tf.a.numpy()}, obj.b: {obj_tf.b.numpy()}')
```

Output:

```
Init.     -- class.a: 1.0 | obj.a: 1.0, obj.b: 1.0
after add -- class.a: 6.0 | obj.a: 6.0, obj.b: 6.0
after sub -- class.a: 4.0 | obj.a: 4.0, obj.b: 4.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is a class attribute. `b` is an instance attribute.

However, augmented assignments like

```
self.a += to_add
self.a -= to_sub
```

are not modifying the class attribute you think you are accessing via the instance. They are really equivalent to

```
self.a = self.a.__iadd__(to_add)
self.a = self.a.__isub__(to_sub)
```

so the first time one is used, the class attribute is accessed on the RHS, but a new instance attribute is then created, and that instance attribute shadows the class attribute in all future calls.

If you want to modify a class attribute via an instance, you need to be explicit about it. One possible solution:

```
type(self).a += to_add
```

---

Your TensorFlow code doesn't make any assignments, augmented or otherwise. It's simply a method call on whatever `self.a` resolves to, which is the class attribute. No new instance attribute is ever created.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is helpful. However, I don't want to modify the class attribute. The output from the first part of code is what I want to get, and I expected to observe the same behavior when using TensorFlow, i.e. `assign_sub` and `assign_add` to act on the instance attribute, instead of both class and instance attributes. As you mentioned, I need to see what `self.a` resolves to when using TensorFlow.

Comment: It resolves to `myc_tf.a`, as you never define an instance attribute to shadow it. The `assign_add` and `assign_sub` methods mutate whatever object invokes them.

Comment: That is a great point, but then, I cannot understand why in the first code (without TensorFlow), `self.a` resolves to `obj_base.a` (object attribute) instead of `myc_base.a` (class attribute). I did not define an instance attribute `a` there either. Could you please clarify on that as well?

Comment: Yes, you did. As I pointed out, `self.a += ...` is equivalent to `self.a = self.a.__iadd__(...)`. Whatever the original class attribute's `__iadd__` method returns, that is assigned to a new instance attribute the first time it is used. All future uses of `self.a` reference that instance attribute, not the class attribute.

Comment: This is not like the difference between local and global variables, where `x += 1` fails immediately to update a global variable because the assignment make `x` into a local variable *everywhere* in the local scope. `self.a += ...` can happily have `self.a` resolve to a class attribute before defining an instance attribute, because attribute access is *not* a name lookup.

Answer (score 0):

you need to understand the class and local variables when the class initiates with the variables you created and the init() functions. The assign_add() and assign_sub() are updated and wait for the value to update but the python class is to erase once release or re-assign value.

> Sample: Starting at 10 both var1 and var2, the var2 lives with 100 as a local variable spent inside the class and their functions. By var1 is assigned it more 30 as a local variable. Updates can reach var1 as 40, var2 as 10 because var2 is never outside the functions and the result is 100.

```
import os
from os.path import exists
import tensorflow as tf

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Class and Functions
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    var1 = tf.Variable([10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0])
    var2 = tf.Variable([10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0])
    
    def __init__(self, num_outputs):
        super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs
        self.var2 = self.var1 * 10.0
        
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
        shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
        self.num_outputs])

    def call(self, inputs):
        self.var1.assign_add([30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0])
        
        temp = tf.constant( self.var2 ).numpy()
        return temp

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
start = 3
limit = 33
delta = 3

# Create DATA
sample = tf.range(start, limit, delta)
sample = tf.cast( sample, dtype=tf.float32 )

# Initail, ( 10, 1 )
sample = tf.constant( sample, shape=( 10, 1 ) )
layer = MyDenseLayer(10)
data = layer(sample)

print( tf.constant( MyDenseLayer.var1 ).numpy() )
print( tf.constant( MyDenseLayer.var2 ).numpy() )
print( data )
```

> Output: local var1, local var2 ( no assign functions ) and data ( result from class update )

```
[40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40. 40.]
[10. 10. 10. 10. 10. 10. 10. 10. 10. 10.]
[100. 100. 100. 100. 100. 100. 100. 100. 100. 100.]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not addressing my question.

Comment: Examines different class variables and local variables that is exactly to the question is see var1 value changes but var2 is not when data as result is.